# endBackgroundTask errors in Google Analytics on iOS

Tags: ios, google-analytics, today-extension

I constantly get the error message when using Google Analytics (GA) in my Today widget and sometimes even in the main app.

> Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 13, or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.

Stack trace:

```
GAIThread (7)
0  UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError
1  -[UIApplication _endBackgroundTask:]
2  -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:]
3  __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke
4  gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform
5  _dispatch_client_callout
6  _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke
7  _perform
8  -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
9  -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]
10 __21-[GAIDataStore save:]_block_invoke
11 -[GAIDataStore performBlockAndWait:withError:]
12 -[GAIDataStore save:]
13 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher deleteHits:]
14 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:]
15 __NSThreadPerformPerform
16 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
17 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
18 __CFRunLoopRun
19 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
21 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run]
22 +[GAI threadMain:]
23 __NSThread__start__
24 _pthread_body
25 _pthread_start
26 thread_start
```

[image: stack trace]

In Today widgets, UIApplication is hidden. The GA library can access it but it is not a good idea. Maybe it means that GA should not be used in Today widgets, but there is no reference talking about that.

I am using GoogleAnalyticsServicesiOS_3.13. It is not the latest, but the changelogs indicate no changes in 3.14 and 3.15 in GA. If it is a bug, where can I report it? The submit button in the issue in Google Code is not usable. Is it because Google Code is closed? Interestingly, there were very recent replies in existing issues.

Comment: I see the same error in GoogleAnalytics 3.17.0 + iPhone 4s iOS 9.3 Simulator, no Today Widgets. It does not crash and the app keeps on going. The stack trace is very similar to yours, so I edited your post to include a text format of your stack trace [which would be much more useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846).